# Flutter not creating Java Classes only Kotlin Instead

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, flutter

I am creating a simple flutter project with latest stable version of flutter. The project, I am creating is without any kotlin support because I want to use java but it is still creating only Kotlin MainActivity class by default. is there a way to use java?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are creating a new flutter app using the latest stable version, the default now is Kotlin for android and Swift for IOS. You can read more here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21190

If you want to create a new app using Java for Android and Objective-C for IOS use the following command:

```
flutter create -i objc -a java new_app
```

And if you have an existing app

```
flutter create -i objc -a java .
```

Comment: what if project already exists?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your current flutter project to desired source languages using `flutter create -i swift/objc -a kotlin/java .`, [reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21190)